# Getting undefined step definition warning in Cucumber Protractor setup

Tags: npm, protractor, cucumber, bdd, cucumberjs

I have installed the npm modules locally (find the dependencies details in below package.json) and try to execute the below cucumber feature file and SD but getting **Undefined. Implement..** message.

I have prepared my feature file as below: **Stored in: test/features/sample.feature**

```
 Feature: Running Cucumber with Protractor
 @test
 Scenario: To verify the Search result
  Given I am on home page
```

And implemented the SD as below: **Stored in: test/step_definitions/sample.steps.js**

```
 module.exports = function() {
  this.Given(/^I am on home page$/, function () {
    return browser.get("http://www.google.com");
   });
 }
```

And my **specs & cucumberOpts** in conf.js as below:

```
 specs: [
 './../features/*.feature'
 ],

 cucumberOpts: {
  require: ['./step_definitions/*.steps.js'],
  tags: '@test',
  strict: true,
  format: 'pretty'
 }
```

Installed package.json dependencies details:

```
 "dependencies": {
  "chai": "^4.0.1",
  "chai-as-promised": "^6.0.0",
  "cucumber": "^2.3.0",
  "protractor": "^5.1.2",
  "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^3.1.1"
 }
```

But in execution getting the message as :

```
 1 scenario (1 undefined)
 1 step (1 undefined)
 0m00.000s
```

can anyone help me to come out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with the step definitions themselves.

You seem to be using the old CucumberJS 1.x syntax for the 2.x framework.

Here's the update to the step definition provided using 2.x syntax:

```
var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(({Given, When, Then}) => {

  Given(/^I am on home page$/, function () {
    return browser.get("http://www.google.com");
  });

});
```